# Is it possible to make react-modal transparent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

So I've added modal to my project. Now I've added it with installing a package called react-modal.

Everything works great, I just can't make it transparent.

When users get on a single article page, if he wants, on a click a button opens a modal with a form. Now I want to keep the form box centered, everything else transparent(so a user can see the background).

Now react-modal uses `customStyles` and I've tried adding into it `backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'` and few other `backgroundColor` but nothing really worked. I've also tried adding `transparent={true}` into the `<Modal />` but that doesn't work.

Here where I use modal:

```
import Modal from 'react-modal';

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

const customStyles = {
  content: {
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    right: 'auto',
    bottom: 'auto',
    marginRight: '-50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  },
};

<Modal
  isOpen={isOpen}
  onRequestClose={toogleModal}
  style={customStyles}
  transparent={true}
  contentLabel='Forma'
>
```

And here is a picture when the modal is open:
[image: modal]

It's only saying that u need to register first, and if u have an account it opens a form.

So is it even possible to make it transparent? I want to keep just this box with an outline, and everything that is white, to make it transparent so users can see the background page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the styling was done by something else that you set earlier (or from other styling library). Can you post more code of the content: the one with the "Please register first"? Also you can try opacity: '50%' (or whatever percent you want).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q60wLs5n/ Here you can find the code. Main component is Article.js, and then onclick class the RequestFrom. and its rendering modal form. Opacitiy doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a cleaner code (particularly the "Please register first" portion)? I want to help you, but I can't go through all that mess.

Comment: It's magically started working. Honestly i dont know why, I've entered site right now, and opacity is there. Thank you on your help

Comment: I think I got it. In this: <div className='p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white'>
          Please register first..
        </div>  Remove the className='p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white' and replace it with something like style={{color: 'black'}} and just play around with the style. Let me know if that works.